# coordinates for google maps from MySQL database, the right way for optimization?

Tags: jquery, mysql, optimization, google-maps-api-3

Is there a right way of getting coordinates from mysql for Google Maps?

The current way I'm doing is I have jQuery script to get coordinates from a populated element which I use MySQL to populate a list of coordinates.

```
// jQuery script to get the coordinates

var coordArray = [];

$(".marker").each(function(index,div)
{

 var coords = $(this).data("coords").split(",");
 coordArray.push([coords[0],coords[1]]);

});


//while loop in PHP and I have displayed the coordinates within a <div> element:

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 <div class="marker" data-coords="<?php echo $row['lat'].",".$row['lng'];?>">stuff</div>
}
```

Is there a better way of doing so? Or would this be okay as well?

Comment: use JSON.. much more efficient

Comment: @charlietfl do you mind giving an example how I would do something? Or if there's an example of how to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your php you would create an array of the values from  DB in your `while` loop. Then output this array to a javascript variable using `json_encode`

```
$arr=array();
while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $arr[]=array( $row['lat'], $row['lng']);
}

echo `<script>var markerData='. json_encode( $arr).';</script>';
```

This will create a JavaScript array in page you would loop over to create markers:

```
<script>
var markerData=[ [100,40], [99,37]/* etc*/];
</script>
```

You could also retirve the JSOn data using AJAX depending on your needs